# How to autohide/unhide Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

Im very unfamiliar with writing VBA code, or any code for that matter.  I currently have a sheet where column B pulls data (names) from another sheet. In column A I have this formula for the corresponding data in column B   =IF(B49=" ","Hide","")

I am only working with rows 48-330.

I am trying to write a macro that will hide any row that has the word Hide in column A and will unhide any row that is blank in column A.  I have tired writing a few different codes but feel like I am going in circles and not getting anywhere.  This is what I know for sure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You can add a filter to the data and filter out the `Hide` rows.

Comment: As this file is shared with hundreds of people every year with my work, most of them would be clueless as to how to use a filter, I want it fool proof so once the macro is embedded the user doesn't have to do any work.